# Trouble using NSDictionary convenience init in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, nsdictionary

I seem to be having a problem trying to create an NSDictionary in Swift using one of the convenience intializers.  My confusion though lies in the fact that the error says my function signature is wrong, yet I'm using the function signature that XCode autocompleted for me.

My Code:

```
var query = NSDictionary(objects: [kSecClass, kSecAttrService, kSecAttrAccount, kSecReturnData], forKeys: [kSecClassGenericPassword, "healthBIT.lastSync", key, true])
```

The XCode provided signature:

```
var query = NSDictionary(objects: <#[AnyObject]#>, forKeys: <#[AnyObject]#>)
```

The error when compiling is: Extra argument 'forKeys' in call

What am I missing here? Am I just too sleep deprived to see the obvious? Or is it just a stupid mistake derived from my relative inexperience with Swift?

PS: I am trying to use NSDictionary here instead of a normal Swift dict because Swift dicts can't store mixed types, and I need to pass this to the underlying C based Keychain API.

Comment: Ok as usual after posting a question, I start to see the light.  Not completely mind you, but I see an issue.  Apparently arrays in Swift suffer from the same limitation as dicts, and can not store mixed types.  The XCode error given on my code above is misleading and the actual issue seems to be that my keys array has mixed types.  Grr what kind of stupid modern language doesn't allow mixed types :(

Comment: I tested your code on playground and it works... so I wonder what the problem is. Besides, you can declare a swift dictionary as [String : AnyObject], although I don't know if it would work with a C based API

Comment: Ok ignore that - I realize now that you're using different types for the key. That's probably not possible because a key type has to implement the `Hashable` protocol, but `AnyObject` doesn't have it

Comment: Interesting about the AnyObject thing.  The Swift docs are a tad misleading then, though I guess they aren't TECHNICALLY incorrect since AnyObject is a concrete type.  I'll give that a try though I'll probably run into casting issues.  Also odd that it works for you in Playground when it very definitely does not work for me, and when I try to break it down XCode gives me an error on the mixed values for the keys (which I actually have backwards in my code where the keys and values are reversed lol)

Comment: Ah ok - at beginning I though you had swapped values with keys, then after reading your comment I thought that was on purpose (although using a boolean for a key sounds very unusual :)). Instead my original deduction was correct. As for casting, yeah I think you will (actually more than casting it's converting) because if looks like you're using C strings

Comment: The AnyObject thing doesn't seem to work either `var secValues: [AnyObject] = [kSecClassGenericPassword, "healthBIT.lastSync", key, true]` still gives a mixed types error.  I'm starting to feel I should just drop into Obj-C to do this bit, but that seems a failure of the language if I do.

Comment: What's the type of the `key` variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62928/discussion-between-jwvanderbeck-and-antonio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a discussion in chat, it turned out the problem is about the `key` variable referenced from the code sample provided in the question, which comes from a `for` loop:

```
for key in lastSync {
    ...
}
```

the error is that `key` is a `(key, value)` tuple, and that's causing issues when using it in a `NSDictionary` (objc types cannot handle swift specific features, such as generics, tuples, etc.).

The problem is solved by expanding the tuple accordingly:

```
for (key, value) in lastSync {
    ...
}
```

or, if `value` is not used:

```
for (key, _) in lastSync {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Antonio!  Misleading XCode errors for the win :)